# Laravel Passport 401 error - "invalid_credentials","message":"The user credentials were incorrect."

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Why after moving dev server to production all authentication requests begun returning with 401 status:

```
// $request contains 'passport' and 'username' fields
$request->request->add([
    "client_id"     => 'env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID')',
    "client_secret" => 'env('PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET')',
    "grant_type"    => 'password',
    "scope"          => '',
]);
$tokenRequest = $request->create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $request->all());
$passportResponse = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

Env values shouldn't be accessed that way - but rather as
[configuration values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#accessing-configuration-values).

Also, after editing .env file, to update configuration:
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan config:clear`.

Answer (score -1):

- check in database the record with client_id if has value for
  password_client equal 1
- if no change value password_client to 1

Comment: elaborate your answer